# Why do relational databases use 2PC for distributed transactions over the likes of Paxos?

Tags: distributed-systems, database-theory

Paxos is more powerful and in the famous writing "Consensus on Transaction Commit" : http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64636/tr-2003-96.pdf, Jim Gray and Leslie Lamport describe 2PC as a special case of Paxos.

Why do relational database use 2PC in real world? Also 2PC is not fault tolerant because it uses a single coordinator whose failure can cause the protocol to block.

Comment: Google's Spanner is a relational database and it uses Paxos.

Comment: Probably because its implementation isn't trivial on strong transactional systems. Even tho, this is changing lately, ie: https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/04/13/masterless-distributed-queue/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the reasons is the message complexity. For N nodes, 2PC will require 3N to be exchanged whereas Paxos requires 4N. Also, Paxos adds sequence numbers to each message which adds a significant overhead to the overall execution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A follow up question, Wikipedia mentions : "he greatest disadvantage of the two-phase commit protocol is that it is a blocking protocol. If the coordinator fails permanently, some cohorts will never resolve their transactions: After a cohort has sent an agreement message to the coordinator, it will block until a commit or rollback is received." How do real world production services resolve these problems?